# Restrict Activity Types by Contact Type(s)

Tags: activities, contact-types

Is there a way to disable certain activity types based on the contact type?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your post. You may find you get more helpful answers if you could provide more detail about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this has not been delivered by anyone as yet but there was some substantive discussion about ACL and Activity Types [here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/ACLs+for+Activities+and+Cases)